# Insert parameter in a string with C

Tags: c, string

I would like to run the following OS X command:

```
md5 <<< 'password'
```

Password is actually supposed to be a parameter, therefore I would like to know how can I "concatenate / insert" a string into another, just like we can do with `printf`:

```
char password[] = "password";
//Something like this:
char command[] = ("md5 <<< '%s'", password);
```

How is it possible in C?

Comment: [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)?

Comment: Thanks alk. I didn't know exactly how to ask therefore I was also not able to find an answer.

Answer (score -1):

strcat I think do the job :char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src).

```
char res[30]; //malloc would be better
strcpy(res, "md5 <<< ");
strcat(res, password);
```

Comment: A guess is not an optimal answer. You should at least show how to do it.